# deriving an implicit Runge Kutta method from its Butcher tableau

Tags: runge-kutta-methods

I would like to use the Gauss–Legendre method of order four (which is a particular Runge Kutta method) to solve numerically an ode but I find only it's Butcher Tableau and I fail to derive the method .
You can find the Tableau here :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods
then search for Gauss-Legendre methods paragraph and it's the first tableau . 
using $$y_{n+1}=y_n + h \sum_{i=1}^s b_i k_i$$

with $$k_i=f(t_n+c_i h,y_n+ h \sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij}k_j)$$

I find for my tableau :
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{2} (k_1+k_2) $$
$$k_1=f(t_n+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}) h,y_n+ \frac{h}{4} k_1 +
(\frac{h}{4}+ \frac{h \sqrt{3}}{6}) k2)$$
$$k_2=f(t_n+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}) h,y_n+ \frac{h}{4} k_2 +
(\frac{h}{4}- \frac{h \sqrt{3}}{6}) k1)$$

using some substitution we can get :
$$k_1=f(t_n+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6})h, 
\frac{1}{2}y_{n+1}+ \frac{1}{2} y_n +
\frac{h \sqrt{3}}{6} k2)$$

there is this extra term $ \frac{h \sqrt{3}}{6} k2$ which I can't find any way to deal with.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: This IS already the method. You have a system of two equations for $k_1$ and $k_2$ you need to solve.

Comment: ok thanks I was trying to find a simplification like for the trapezoidal rule but there is none right ?

Comment: Additional remark: For some, usually simple, RK schemes it is possible to express the scheme only in terms of $y_n$ and $y_{n+1}$. I dont think thats the case here though...

Comment: that's what I was trying to do but yes I can't find anyway to do it

Comment: As I said, I dont think it is doable due to the cross-dependency.

Comment: if you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

Summary of my comments: :-)

This IS already the method. You have a system of two equations for $k_1$ and $k_2$ you need to solve.

For some, usually simple, RK schemes it is possible to express the scheme only in terms of $y_n$ and $y_{n+1}$. However due to the cross-dependency I am pretty confident that is not possible in this specific case...

Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200817/understanding-the-butcher-tableau-of-implicit-midpoint-method) for an example of the derivation of the implict midpoint rule starting from the butcher tableau.